# How I can save image with using a best practices in Laravel (php)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, php-8.1, solid

I have a code with saving a article. With my article I have a photo ('img'), which I want to add to Model Article in field 'img'.
How I can do it with using a best practices in Laravel?

ArticleController:

```
public function __construct(Article $article, ArticleService $articleService)
{
    $this->article = $article;
    $this->articleService = $articleService;
}

public function store(StoreRequest $request)
{
    if($request->file())
    {
        $file = ($request->file())['img'];
        $fileName = time().'_'.rand().'.'.$file->extension();
        $file->move(public_path('img/articles'), 
        $fileName);
        $request->img= $fileName;
    }
    $article = $this->article->create($request->validated());

    return redirect(route('article.index',['article' => $article->id]));
}
```

Model Article:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'title_en',
        'body_en',
        'title_pl',
        'body_pl',
        'title_ru',
        'body_ru'
    ];

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function ($model) {
        $model->slug = Str::slug($model->title_en);
    });
}
```

Comment: In the code you've shared there is no image upload. What have you tried?

Comment: I have edited my questions right now and have added some line of codes with 'not best practices'..

Comment: There's a whole section in the docs on handling file uploads properly. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads `$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');` is all it takes.

Comment: The use of the `best practices` term does not fool anybody you know

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provide a more efficient way to store file, in docs.[https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads]
it provides a store() which accepts storage path.
you can simply do this like:

```
$data = $request->only('field1',...);
if($request->hasFile('filename')) {
$file = $request->file('filename');
$data['key_name'] = $file->store('pathname');
}
$article->create($data);
```

Note: file should be a laravel file not string, you can check it with isFile().